# How to avoid Internet Explorer script error

Tags: internet-explorer

I've created a VB.net program that navigates web pages with the help of a tutorial I found on the net.

Now I'm trying to navigate the PHP scripts that I've created. But there is always this Internet Explorer script error that I am seeing. Which I do not see when I access the PHP scripts on Firefox - or in any other browser. What do I do with this, what might be the cause?

I cannot use the browser's because I'm not yet good at designing in PHP so I use VB.net as my interface.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the "this" in your *"there is always this internet explorer script error that I am seeing"*:

You are aware that PHP scripts need to be executed by the server, for example by Apache with `mod_php`? When not having the server execute the PHP code, your browser will not get just HTML, but also the non-executed PHP code that is still embedded within that HTML, which it does not understand. So: where does your program fetch the PHP files from?

(If I understand your problem correctly then you would see the same effect when just dragging local PHP files into your browser, without using any server. Does that indeed give you the same problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off script error notifications.

Uncheck "**Display a notification about every script error**":

[image]

<sup>Click for larger image</sup>

That way you won't see script errors in Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is not a real solution - if what-ever causes the script error remains then this will affect other IE users who do not have the option turned off if the script/page is made publically available. The problems shoudl be located and fixed rather than hidden.

Comment: @David. Granted. But given that the OP didn't give any code, or the actual error he was seeing, it sounded like he didn't want it fixed per se. It sounded like, to me anyway, that he wants the errors hidden. Especially when he's careful to point out it's in ie.